# Registry and file system change identification

Tags: c++, filesystems, registry, virtualization, hook

Is there a Coding way in C++ to find out the changes happened in Registry and file system. I need to find the changes happened to file system and registry after a software installion.

There is filesystemwatcher in c# to identify filesystem changes. However, I need that to implement in C++  for both registry and files.

Comment: Do you need the precise order of changes, or is a simple before-and-after comparison enough?

Comment: I dont need the orders of the change. I just need the comparison between before and after of installation. Also i need the Key/File Names which are Created/Modified due to that installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For monitoring registry keys you can use `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue()`, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724892(v=VS.85).aspx). For files you'd use `ReadDirectoryChangesW()`, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465(VS.85).aspx).